# Getting a "Unexpected character '<' at line 1, column 0." while trying to connect to Google using GoogleApis library

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, google-oauth

I'm using Google Apis, instead of Google Sign In, to connect to Google on my app because I'm developping with Xamarin.

This is the library I'm using : https://github.com/xamarin/google-apis

When I'm logging in, i get this error :

**Authentication Error**
Unexpected character '<'. At line 1, column 0.

Maybe it's because my AccessTokenUrl is not good, but I've tried many things. I know for a fact that my ClientId, my RedirectUrl and my Secret are okay.

When logging in, Google asks correctly for the good permissions that I want, but after I accept, this is when I receive the error.

I've tried finding the request to see if there was the '<' in it but had no luck accessing it.

Is there a good way to connect to Google with Xamarin using this library or I'm just doing something bad?

Should I just do it nativaly on iOS and Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a similar problem using Xamarin.Auth to hit a custom OAuth service (i.e. not Google). In my case, the accessTokenUrl pointed to an action on a controller that was entirely protected by the `[Authorize]` attribute. Naturally, the user was required to login before hitting the `/oauth/authorize` endpoint using a web browser, but the request to `/oauth/token` to exchange the resulting authorization code for an access token was not inside the same web browser/session. It was trying to get back token data in JSON format but was being redirected to an HTML login screen. Once I changed the token endpoint for anonymous access, things started working (Note: A valid authorization code cannot be obtained without authenticating).

**General Recommendations**

The error message strongly suggests that the response coming back is HTML (or at least some form of XML). This could be an authentication redirect as it was in my scenario, or possibly some sort of error page. I would first start by setting up a proxy. I used [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to uncover some interesting information. You will need to configure SSL on the proxy to see anything except high level information. This will show the exact requests coming out of your app to the OAuth application.

Another technique I used was simulating the requests that the OAuth2Authenticator would be making in a web browser and/or Postman. The first request would be to authorize:

```
https://your.domain.here/oauth/authorize?client_id=<some_client_id>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyour.domain.here%2F&response_type=code&scope=<some_scope>&state=<some_state>
```

That endpoint should be protected, so you will likely be redirected to something like this:

```
https://your.domain.here/Account/Login?returnurl=%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3D<some_client_id>%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fyour.domain.here%252F%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3D<some_scope>%26state%3D<some_state>
```

After authenticating, the authorize endpoint should redirect to your redirect URI with the authorization code and state included as query string parameters. You will use the code in the next step.

Lastly, using a fresh web browser (i.e. new session), you should hit the token endpoint with your new authorization code and other client information.

```
https://your.domain.here/oauth/token?client_id=<some_client_id>&client_secret=<some_secret>&grant_type=<your_grant_type>&code=<your_authorization_code>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyour.domain.here%2F
```

If the response is not JSON data, it should give you an indication about what is failing with Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error.
Solved by using https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token as AccessTokenUrl